# Daterange histogram with SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, histogram, date-range

I have a table with date ranges like the following:

```
start                 | end
2020-07-25 20:37:00     2020-07-25 20:44:00
2020-07-25 21:37:00     2020-07-25 22:44:00
2020-07-26 07:11:00     2020-07-27 10:50:00
...
```

At the end, I want a histogram which shows for every hour of a day how many date ranges "overlaps" each hour.
So the resulting histogram consists of 24 bars.

How do I do this in SQL for MySQL? (Side note: I'm using TypeORM, but I'm able to write plain SQL statements)

I only found solutions calculating and grouping by the length of the individual intervals with `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, but that's not what I want to achieve.

In future I may want to show the same histogram not per hour but per minute of a day or per day of a month and so on. But I assume that's simple to do once I get the idea of the query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is the brute force method:

```
with recursive hours as (
      select 0 as hh
      union all
      select hh + 1
      from hours
      where hh < 23
     )
select h.hh, count(t.start)
from hours h left join
     t 
     on start >= '2020-07-25' + interval h.hh hour and
        end < '2020-07-25' + interval (h.hh + 1) hour
where end < '2020-07-25' + interval 1 day and
      start >= '2020-07-25'
group by h.hh
order by h.hh;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what are table "hours" and "t"? I only have one table, let's call it tableX, with the "start" and "end" columns

Comment: @KristofKomlossy . . . `hours` is a CTE (used recursively) and `t` is the name of your table.